# How to make a text file give you a string array

Tags: java, text

I have a string array:

> String[] word ={"atom","electron","oxyegn","explosion","combustion","flask","laser","molecule","ion","bond"};\

But i need to get this string from a text file that I would needed to have created. Please help me, I need this for my java assignment which it to build a hangman game (these are the words that are going to be guessed).

Answer (score 1):

you can store these values in CSV (comma separated variables) in a file, like below.

```
atom,electron,oxyegn,explosion,combustion,flask,laser,molecule,ion,bond
```

While retrieving, you can read the contents of the file and split the line by comma like below

```
String s = ...read line form file...
String[] word = s.split(",");
```

Also, if you need to save some new values, you can do something like below (if you are using Java8)

```
String s = Stream.of(word).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
... save s in file...
```

Comment: Hi, thnx for the help, do you need code for creating the file, I am pretty new to incorporating text files into java, so the more specific the better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StreamTokenizer :

```
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
Reader reader = new StringReader("atom electron ...");//replace this with a FileReader in you case
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(reader);
while(tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
    wordList.add(tokenizer.sval);
}
reader.close();
```

And if you really need an array :

```
String[] words = wordList.toArray(new String[worldList.size()];
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Since i am just learning file readers could you specify an example of how I may do this step by step?

Comment: replace the ``Reader reader = new StringReader("atom electron ...");`` with ``Reader reader = new FileReader("/path/to/your/textfile");``

Comment: Note that StreamTokenizer is a part of the java standard API (``java.io.StreamTokenizer``)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use any external imports, the following code would work:

```
public class TestStrings {

    private String[] namesList;

    public TestStrings() {
        String filePath = "path/to/file";
        this.namesList = readFile(filePath).split(",");
    }

    private static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, how do i use the string array, nameslist, outside of the main ?

Comment: Set the array to an instance variable within a constructor.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, still learning the basics, could you show me an example please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

```
package org.gooeybits.meltdown.utilities;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Yohanan Ben Abrahams.
 */
public class Main {
    private String[] words = null;

    public Main() {}

    public Main run() {
        this.words = loadWordsFromFile("/your/path/to/file.txt");
        return this;
    }

    private String[] loadWordsFromFile(String url) {
        String currentLine;
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(url));

            while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = currentLine.split("\\W");
                words.addAll(Arrays.asList(split));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.print("Could not open the word file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
    }

    public String[] getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = new Main().run().getWords();
        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }

}
```